# Error when running unit tests in automated build since VS upgrade to 2013 on TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, msbuild, tfsbuild

I started creating automated builds in TFS 2012 using a build server with VS2012 on it. Everything was running fine, but then we updated the build server to VS2013(still with TFS 2012). Now no units execute. I get the error:

Handle Test Run Exception

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities, 
Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can find that file on the build server but only version 12 under vs2013.

Im lost as to what to do as I dont know what is forcing the Test Runner to use version 11 or how to change it.

Is it possible that since the build controller is tfs 2012, it is somehow forcing the Test Runner in the build to use version 11 instead of version 12 on the build server? Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have VS2012 installed on your build agent machine?

Comment: No the build server/agent had VS2012 uninstalled when VS2013 was added..

Comment: Reinstall it back and things should be back to normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have VS Professional or later on your build server to run automated tests as a part of your build process.

Here since TFS is still at 2012 the test activities are referring the 11.0 dlls and installing VS2012 should help resolve this issue.

This is a known bug being tracked.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138.aspx

> To run unit tests, or coded UI tests, you must install Visual Studio
>   Professional or later

Comment: We have VS 2013 Ultimate installed and I was hoping that would be enough... I will try get VS 2012 back on there and report back. Thanks for the quick respsonse..

Comment: Instead of completely reinstallig VS 2012, I was recommendeded to install Agents for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. I have done this and now the tests execute, however I cannot get any Code Coverage. I have turned it on in the build settings, tried a .runsettings file, and nothing. No errors eithers, just "No Code Coverage Results". Any ideas? Still related to the complete VS2012 not being on there?

Comment: That is neither suggested nor supported. You must install VS2012.